# Compare a string within the API response and get a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a REST API endpoint that we need to query to get the data within the response I need to filter for a value. Below is my code for querying the endpoint

```
    public  async Task<RmRoom> GetRoomsDeatil()
    {
        RmRoom retRoom = new RmRoom();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_iconfiguration.GetSection("RM").GetSection("BaseAddress").Value);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/rooms").ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                retRoom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RmRoom>(result);
            }
            return retRoom;
        }
    }
```

RmRoom Model class is like

```
public partial class RmRoom
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON response is like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A2 SA",
        "description": "Blu"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "A5 PA",
        "description": "Red"
    }
]
```

With in my logic I need to call the above GetRoomsDeatil() method and get all the details and check if my String `updatedName` matches the name field (string before the first space like A2 or A5) in the response and get just its ID

```
 public IQueryable<Inventory> GetInventories(InventorySearch inventorySearch, string rmName)
        {
            string updatedName = rmName.Substring(0, rmName.IndexOf(' '));

            RmRoom rmDetail = GetRoomsDeatil();

            string rmID = "";
```

I am not sure how to check that with the response object and get only its ID.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First off, get rid of the .result in your async method please

Anyway, looks like your response is List and not RmRoom (based on the Json)

so why not just go

```
public  async Task<RmRoom> GetRoomsDetail(string roomName)
{
    RmRoom retRoom = new RmRoom();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_iconfiguration.GetSection("RM").GetSection("BaseAddress").Value);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/rooms").ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var retRooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RmRoom>>(result);
            foreach(var room in retRooms)
                 if(RoomNamesMatch(room.name, roomName))
                      return room;
            throw new Exception($"No room found with name {roomName}");
        }
        else //format this with whatever info you wanna share
            throw new Exception($"Request to get rooms failed with message {response.Message}");
    }
} 
private bool RoomNamesMatch(string name1, string name2){
    //put matching logic here, or make this a method on the room object, up to you
}
```